# Gronwall Lemma.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $x'(t)=f(x)$ such that $(x_1,x_2)\mapsto(-x_1+2(x_2),-2(x_1)-x_2)$.

I need to show that for two solutions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ of the above differential equation we have:

$\lVert x(t)-y(t)\rVert \leq e^{-t}\lVert x(0)-y(0)\rVert$

Using Gronwall's Lemma, I have somehow picked up a root(5) and cannot seem to get the required answer. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: wouldn't the eigenvalues be $-1\pm 2i$?

Answer (score 1):

It often helps to look at $\|x-y\|^2$ instead of $\|x-y\|$. Indeed,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\|x-y\|^2 = 2\langle x'-y',x-y\rangle  =
2\langle f(x)-f(y),x-y\rangle =2\langle f(x-y),x-y \rangle
\tag1 $$
where we get help from $f$ being linear. As a matter of fact, $f$ is represented by the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ -2 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \tag2$$
Any matrix can be written as the sum of symmetric and skew-symmetric matrices:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\tag3$$
You may want to observe that the skew-symmetric part cancels out when we calculate $\langle Av,v\rangle$ 
for any vector $v$. Therefore, $\langle Av,v\rangle=-\|v\|^2$. Now (1) takes the form
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\|x-y\|^2 = -2\|x-y\|^2 
\tag4 $$
which is a very  simple ODE for the function $u=\|x-y\|^2$.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot see how the skew symmetric matrix cancels out?

Comment: @Seany Just plug in a vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and see what happens.